# java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Jun 4 2020 8:58:15 AM' could not be parsed at index 0

Tags: java

I get the error:

> `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException`:
>   Text 'Jun 4 2020 8:58:15 AM' could not be parsed at index 0

```
String ajourTsAdjusted = "Jun 4 2020 8:58:15 AM";
DateTimeFormatter dt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d yyyy h:mm:ss a");
LocalDateTime ajDate = LocalDateTime.parse(ajourTsAdjusted, dt);
```

Can someone see what I did not do right here?

Regards Flemming

Comment: This code runs fine on my system... Maybe provide a `Locale` to the `DateTimeFormatter` if your system language is not English, like `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d yyyy h:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);`

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your system language is not English.

This assumption is made because of your error language stating *(..) cannot be parsed at index 0*, that is the beginning of the date resp. pattern.

There, you have an abbreviation of a month name and those abbreviations differ from language to language. In my country, *Jun* is the abbreviation for *June* in English, but by coincidence, it is the German abbreviation for *Juni*, too, which makes this code work on my system.
The `DateTimeFormatter` will use the language setting of your system if you don't provide a different/specific `Locale`.

To make sure an English datetime will be parsed, provide a `Locale` to the `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String ajourTsAdjusted = "Jun 4 2020 8:58:15 AM";
    DateTimeFormatter dt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d yyyy h:mm:ss a",
                                                        Locale.ENGLISH);
    LocalDateTime ajDate = LocalDateTime.parse(ajourTsAdjusted, dt);
    System.out.println(ajDate);
}
```

This will output the ISO-formatted datetime `String` like this:

```
2020-06-04T08:58:15
```